# Rewrite Codes From htaccess to Nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I can't convert below rewrite rules from htaccess to nginx

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|images|inc|lang)
RewriteRule ^anasayfa$  index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^girisyap$  giris.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kayitol$  kayit.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cikis$  cikis.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bankalar$  bankalar.php [L]
RewriteRule ^instagram-ucretsiz-takipci$  ucretsiz-takipci.php [L]


RewriteRule ^hizmetler/(.*)/(.*)$ hizmet.php?h=$1&hizmet=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^paketler/(.*)/(.*)$ paket.php?p=$1&paket=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^satinal/(.*)/(.*)$ buy.php?p=$1&paket=$2 [QSA]
```

I tried below converter but it doesn't help:
http://www.anilcetin.com

Need help please...
Thank you.

Comment: What are the two `RewriteCond`s supposed to do? I don't see any benefit for these.

Comment: The other rules look rather straightforward to me, see https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ for examples.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thank you very much it helped a lot :)